# Rendering AngularJS HTML page on server side NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have NodeJS server + AnglarJS page.
All works.
Do working examples or frameworks that allow the download page on the server NodeJS and fill it and return to the client a static page. It is necessary for Browsers  IE 5-8 (90% clients).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for Node.js - you can easily serve up a single static page and then use a link to redirect users to your Angular app (using a 'login' page, for example).

Here is an example of a very basic Express app.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

The req (request) and res (response) are the exact same objects that Node provides, so you can invoke req.pipe(), req.on('data', callback) and anything else you would do without Express involved.
The app starts a server and listens on port 3000 for connection. It will respond with "Hello World!" for requests to the homepage. For every other path, it will respond with a 404 Not Found.

Save the code in a file named app.js and run it with the following command.

`$ node app.js`

Then, load `http://localhost:3000/` in a browser to see the output.

Comment: I use node-static. He return Angular html page. But i want complete page on server and return static html. All get and post request from page and all ng-repeat... working on node server. Finally return to user static page (Result of work AngularJS: NOT template + controller, only statik HTML)

Comment: If you just want a static HTML file served, you could do it this way with express: `app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and then just go to the url: `/public/mypage.html` and it will render without any Angular interference.

Comment: no. I want the page to be completed using a AngilarJS. Worked all functions and directives. At the moment, my page is a template that is filled with all sorts of means of directives. I want to countries completed on the server side. A returned result.
For example in the page is written <html>{{username}}</html> but the server will return the already completed <html>"John Smit"</html>